# White space being added above and below SVG when exporting in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I am having an issue exporting an SVG with multiple layers. When I export the SVG, a ton of white space is being added above and below the actual image. I selected all the objects on the artboard and went to `object>artboards>fit to selected art` and in Illustrator it looks fine(no unwanted white space) but as soon as I export it I am getting a ton of white-space added. How can I export as SVG so that there isn't any space added above and below the image?

**EDIT:** When I deselect everything and choose `object>artboards>fit to artwork bounds` it appears to add in the white space I am seeing in the final SVG. How can I crop the artwork bounds?

Comment: If there's a clipping mask, fitting to artwork bounds will take as limits the mask content. Is there any clipping mask in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have art beyond the artboard inside a clipping mask.

When exporting make sure that you have *Use Artboards* checked.

[image]